# Uploading file to server in Android - uploads the last one

Tags: android

I have a Sqlite table which stores 3 files and when I want to read them from table it works fine but when I want to upload to server, it just uploads the last one 3 times. I don't know what is wrong with my code please give me a solution for this problem. appreciate thanks

This is how I call from Activity:

```
List<MediaFiles> mediaFiles = mfh.getAllFiles();
        for (MediaFiles mf : mediaFiles) {
            filePath = mf.getFile();
            lat = Double.parseDouble(mf.getGeolat());
            longi = Double.parseDouble(mf.getGeolng());
            String log = "Id: " + mf.getId() + " ,File: " + mf.getFile() + " ,latitued: " + mf.getGeolat() + " ,longitued: " + mf.getGeolng();
            Log.d("File Table Row: ", log);
            new UploadFileToServerMain().execute();
        }
```

And this is the Uploader class:

```
private class UploadFileToServerMain extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        //progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {

        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(global.getURL()+"fileUpload.php");

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("latitued", new StringBody(lat+""));
            entity.addPart("longitued", new StringBody(longi+""));
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            entity.addPart("token",new StringBody(global.getMyToken()));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);
        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        //showAlert(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

The Logcat:
[image]

Comment: Where does the AsyncTask get your filePath variable from?

Right now you loop through all three files but you only store the last filepath in the filePath variable. So when you start the AsyncTasks they will only use the same filePath. Try to debug there or log to see if this is true.

Edit: If it's the filePath that's the same, you should send in the filePath to the AsyncTask as a parameter and use it in there.

Comment: The filePath is defined at top of my activity

Comment: How to pass the filePath as a param to UploadFileToServerMain?

Comment: So change the AsyncTask to:

private class UploadFileToServerMain extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

And then like this:

  @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             if(params.length != 1) {
                 Log.w(TAG, "Wrong number of parameters, expecting a filePath");
                return null;
            }

            String filePath = params[0];

            return uploadFile(filePath);
        }

Edit: And when you start the AsyncTask you can then call:

new UploadFileToServerMain().execute(filePath);

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution(Passing the parameter to AsyncTask class.)

```
List<MediaFiles> mediaFiles = mfh.getAllFiles();
    for (MediaFiles mf : mediaFiles) {
        lat = Double.parseDouble(mf.getGeolat());
        longi = Double.parseDouble(mf.getGeolng());
        String log = "Id: " + mf.getId() + " ,File: " + mf.getFile() + " ,latitued: " + mf.getGeolat() + " ,longitued: " + mf.getGeolng();
        Log.d("File Table Row: ", log);
        new UploadFileToServerMain(mf.getFile()).execute();
    }
```

Creating constructor uploader class

```
private class UploadFileToServerMain extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

private String path = null;
public UploadFileToServerMain(String path){
        this.path = path;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String uploadFile() {

    String responseString = null;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(global.getURL()+"fileUpload.php");

    try {
        AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void transferred(long num) {
                        publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                    }
                });

        File sourceFile = new File(path);

        // Adding file data to http body
        entity.addPart("latitued", new StringBody(lat+""));
        entity.addPart("longitued", new StringBody(longi+""));
        entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
        entity.addPart("token",new StringBody(global.getMyToken()));

        totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Making server call
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // Server response
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        } else {
            responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                    + statusCode;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    }

    return responseString;

}

}
```